# C# MongoDbDriver insert elements that do not exist

Tags: .net, mongodb, asynchronous, nosql, exists

Consider an array of the following entries:

```
Public Class Potato
{
   string Attribute_1 { get; set }
   decimal Attribute_2 { get; set; }
   DateTimeOffset Attribute_3 { get; set; }
}
```

What would be the most concise way to insert only those elements that are not already in the collection (by composite key using all 3 attributes)?

Currently I'm doing it one by one, but it might not be optimal (and probably should use a transaction?):

```
foreach (var newEntry in newEntries)
{
            var builder = Builders<Potato>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Eq(r => r.Attribute_1, newEntry.Attribute_1)
                         & builder.Eq(r => r.Attribute_2, newEntry.Attribute_2)
                         & builder.Eq(r => r.Attribute_3, newEntry.Attribute_3);

            var cursor = await _collection.FindAsync(filter);

            if (await cursor.AnyAsync())
            {
                return 0;
            }

            await _collection.InsertOneAsync(newEntry);
            return 1;
}
```

Comment: You can explore the "upsert" option of the _update_ method.

Answer (score 0):

Using constraints is might be a good way.

If I don't know wrong, this is exactly what constraints exist for. Why don't you prefer to use indexes?

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: I don't exactly have full control over the DB. And even if I had an index, then again how would I push entries inside? One by one in a regular loop?